# Polymorphic association jpa2 hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, polymorphic-associations

I think im doing something wrong but i cant get working @any annotation on hibernate 4.2.2 with jpa2 1.0.1

The class works ok, but i cant get join.

My code is this:

```
@Entity(name = "conta")
public class Conta {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(name = "empresa_id")
private int empresaId;
private String descricao;

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "tipo"), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "int", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
        @MetaValue(value = "BANCO", targetEntity = Banco.class),
        @MetaValue(value = "CIELO", targetEntity = Cielo.class)
})
@JoinColumn(name = "financeira_id")
private Financeira financeira;
//getters and setters
}
```

Financeira its an interface, Banco.class and Cielo.class implements Conta as well. When i try to fetch from DB i can get all records, but the join doesnt happen.

My code inspection on Intellij IDEA says for *private Financeira financeira* that "**'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Financeira'**". I know or i think i know that this message says that jpa dont have metamodel for @any annotation, but hibernate does, so, this should work right?

**UPDATE**

Got the problem solved by using hibernate native xml configuration.
Now i can persist my objects but i got another problem. I cant fetch the association, im using a factory to fetch de association on @postLoad event, but thats not the right way.

above my xml code.

```
        <any id-type="java.lang.Integer" meta-type="string" name="tipo" cascade="all">
        <meta-value value="BANCO" class="br.com.leaftecnologia.lfadmin.model.financeiro.BANCO" />
        <meta-value value="PLAYSMS" class="br.com.leaftecnologia.lfadmin.model.financeiro.CIELO" />
        <column name="tipo" />
        <column name="financeira_id" /></any>
```

Comment: Do you get your data but it isn't using a join?

Comment: Yes, i get the data from main persistence, but, the @any is ignored, the hibernate dont do the join, i cant get all data, only main data, one table

Comment: Got working now as metioned on post, but cant get hibernate to fetch the association. :/